# SSIS Balanced Data Distributor - Processing one row at time

Tags: sql-server, ssis, balanced-data-distributor

I need some help with the balanced data distributor parallelism feature.

I have an application that works as follows:

- Fetch data from the DB using an OLE DB Origin component
- Send to a balanced data distributor component to distribute the data found between many Script Components that will perform some business logic on each row.

This was working well until recently when I've needed to perform a server migration of the application and for some reason the parallelism feature of the application stopped working and instead of using all the destinations, the balanced data distributor is sending data to only one.

I'm not sure where the problem would be and I've already searched the internet for answers but I've could not find a good lead on my issue.

Did someone already came across such problem? Or have an idea of what the problem could be and would shed some light?

BTW, I don't know if it's of any value but I've set the "AutoAdjustBufferSize" to true

Thanks!

PS. Sorry if I misspelled any word. English is not my main language.